# can't check user profile service cll in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to check the user profile, then authorize it or not in order to access a certain page.
I'm defining this service

```
.factory(
            'accountService',
            function($resource, $http, sessionService, $state) {
                var service = {};
                service.getProfile = function() {
                    $http.get("/myapp/rest/account/getuserprofile").success(function(data) {
                        userProfile = data.userProfile;
                        if (userProfile == "1"){
                            service.isStudent = false;
                            console.log("1", service.isStudent);
                        }
                        else
                            service.isStudent = false;
                        console.log("2", service.isStudent);
                    }).error(function() {
                    });
                    return service.isStudent;
                }                   
                return service;
            })
```

then i'm checking this service

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState,
                        toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    $scope.uiRouterState = $state;
                    if ((toState.data.authenticate
                            &&accountService.getUser())) {
                        $state.go("login");
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    if ((toState.data.teacher &&accountService.isStudent ===1)) {
                        $state.go("home");
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
```

but the problem is that accountService.isStudent is always undefined.
how can I check that?

Comment: Do you want to just check if `accountService.isStudent` is undefined? Or is the problem that `accountService.isStudent` is always undefined so you don't know if the account is a student or not?

Comment: @colelemonz I need to check if the account is a student or not, if it is a student he will not be allowed otherwise it will be allowed to access that page.

Comment: @Med you get data asynchronously but return service.isStudent synchronously. it will be always undefined